# Dart typecasting error

Tags: casting, dart

I have an abstract class `Event` and a concrete subclass that extends it called `PlaceChangeEvent`. Inside an event listener, I have the following code:

```
void onEvent(Event event) {
    PlaceChangeEvent pce = null;
    if(event is PlaceChangeEvent)
        pce = (PlaceChangeEvent)event;      // <== error is here
    else
        throw new Exception("Event is not a PlaceChangeEvent.");

    Place place = pce.place;

    presenterProvider.display(place);
}
```

So if the runtime type of `event` is `PlaceChangeEvent`, then I need to cast the event to that type so that I can access its properties. But I'm getting a compiler error on the typecast, stating:

> A value of type 'Type' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'PlaceChangeEvent'

Where am I going wrong, and what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

In Dart

1. upcasts are implicit. If `B` is a subclass of `A`, then `B b = a` (where `a` is an instance of class `A`) is warning free and silently casts `a` to `B`. In Java you would have needed to write `B b = (B) a`.
2. the dynamic type is an always-present escape hatch. If `B` and `C` are not in the same hierarchy, then temporarily assigning to the dynamic type will make the cast warning-free.

   ```
   B b = someB;
   var tmp = b;
   C c = tmp;
   ```
3. One can do an explicit check using `is`. The `is` check returns true if the object is of the right type. There are also some very simple rules that propagate is-check types. For example, if `is` is used inside an `if` condition, then the corresponding branch uses this information for type-warnings.

   ```
   Object o;
   o.foo();  // warning: foo does not exist on Object.
   if (o is A) {  // assuming that A contains 'foo'.
     o.foo();  // warning-free.
   }
   ```
4. One can explicitly check and throw if a type is not the expected one with `as`. This operator does *not* throw when the left-hand side is `null`.

For your example this boils down to:

No explicit check (1):

```dart
void onEvent(Event event) {
  // Implicit upcast. PlaceChangeEvent is subclass of Event.
  PlaceChangeEvent pce = event;
  Place place = pce.place;
  presenterProvider.display(place);
}
```

With an is-check (3):

```dart
void onEvent(Event event) {
  if (event is PlaceChangeEvent) {
    // Static type system propagates type. No need for variable.
    Place place = event.place;
    presenterProvider.display(place);
  } else {
    // Note: this doesn't look like an exception, but an error.
    throw new Exception("Event is not a PlaceChangeEvent.");
  }
}
```

Using `as` (4):

```dart
void onEvent(Event event) {
  Place place = (event as PlaceChangeEvent).place;
  presenterProvider.display(place);
}
```

Alternatively, if you expect to receive a PlaceChangeEvent, you should simply change the type of the argument:

```dart
void onEvent(PlaceChangeEvent event) {
  Place place = event.place;
  presenterProvider.display(place);
}
```

In checked mode this will catch bad types, and in unchecked mode it will throw when accessing `event.place`. This is generally the preferred way.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
pce = event as PlaceChangeEvent;
```

Comment: Thanks @ringstaff (+1) - but what if the runtime type of `event` is another subclass of `Event` *besides* `PlaceChangeEvent`? Say I have another subclass called `LogEvent`, and at runtime `event` is actually a `LogEvent` (not a `PlaceChangeEvent`)? What happens to the cast?

Comment: Thanks again @ringstaff (+1) - in general, what happens in Dart if the **as** cast fails? Does an exception get thrown, if so, what type? Thanks again!

Comment: @CalifornianAcorn - If the case fails it will throw a TypeError exception (type 'Foo' is not a subtype of type 'PlaceChangeEvent' of 'pce'.

Comment: The line with the cast wouldn't be executed then, because of the contition where you check if event is only a PlaceChangeEvent. In other world, your exception is thrown (repost because I couldn't edit and there was a big typo)