# Dart: If dynamic is a type then access with intellisense?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to OOP and dart. I posted the code below that "works" but intellisense doesn't work with it.

**Problem:**
The `state` getter is dynamic because accessing `settings.state.entity` won't even compile if the return type is `EntityState`. I thought the `if (settings.state is EntityLoaded<Settings>)` type check would allow me to access `.entity.` but I guess that's not how it works.

How do I get intellisense to work again?

```
abstract class EntityState {}

class EntityEmpty extends EntityState {}

class EntityLoaded<T> extends EntityState {
  final T entity;
  EntityLoaded(this.entity);
}
```

```
class SettingsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  // ----------------------------------> _state could be either EntityEmpty or EntityLoaded<T>
  EntityState _state = EntityEmpty();

  SettingsProvider(this._state);

  // EntityState get state => _state --> doesn't let me access .entity code block below.
  get state => _state; // -------------> works without intellisense
}
```

```
final settings = Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context);
if (settings.state is EntityLoaded<Settings>) {
  print(settings.state.entity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
[Dart typecasting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859702/dart-typecasting-error?rq=1)

I had to change `is` Type check to:

```
final state = Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context).state;
if (state is EntityLoaded<Settings>) {
  print(state.entity);
}
```

then I can access `.entity` without warning.